# How to split a numpy array of integers, into chunks that have successive values with a difference below a threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array with positive integers, in ascending order:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([222, 225, 227, 228, 230, 232, 241, 243, 244, 245, 252, 253, 258])
```

I want to split it, into parts, where at each part, each number has **maximum difference** of `2` from the next one.

So the following array should be split as:

```
[[222], [225,227,228,230,232], [241, 243, 244, 245], [252, 253], [258]]
```

Any ideas how I can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), get the indices of differences above threshold with [`flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html), and split with [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
threshold = 2

out = np.array_split(arr, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr)>threshold)+1)
```

output:

```
[array([222]),
 array([225, 227, 228, 230, 232]),
 array([241, 243, 244, 245]),
 array([252, 253]),
 array([258])]
```